# Доступ к ключам словаря из другого метода (C#)

Tags: c#, словари

Не могу получить доступ к ключам словаря dic  из  метода DicOutput. Выдает ошибку "Имя "dic" не существует в данном контексте. Прилагаю код:

```
    // Метод, реализующий ввод словаря
    public static Dictionary<string, string> MyDic()
    {
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Сколько слов вы хотите ввести?: ");
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string engWord;
            string rusWord;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите английское словво: ");
                engWord = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите перевод слова: ");
                rusWord = Console.ReadLine();
                dic.Add(engWord, rusWord);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            while (dic.Count != i);
            Choice();
            return dic;
        }
        //Метод, реализующий вывод словаря
        public static void DicOutput ()
        {
            ICollection<string> keys = dic.Keys;
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно объявить твой словарь dic за пределами метода MyDic. Тогда метод DicOutput увидит эту переменную.
Просто вынеси строчку Dictionary dic = new Dictionary(); за пределы метода.
Учитывая что методы у тебя статические, скорее всего придется и твой список тоже делать статическим, если мне не изменяет память. Я бы объявил список таким образом
public static Dictionary Dic { get; set;} = new Dictionary();

Comment: Достаточно было вывести словарь за метод и все получилось. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Метод не может получить доступ к переменной так как она объявлена в другом методе.

> Контекст метода. Переменные, определенные на уровне метода, являются локальными и доступны только в рамках данного метода. В других методах они недоступны

Просто передавайте словарь параметром в свой метод:

```js
 public static void DicOutput(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
        {
            ICollection<string> keys = dic.Keys;
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Запускаем вот так

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DicOutput(MyDic());
        }
```

Comment: При запуске DicOutput(MyDic()); запускается вместо вывода словаря ввод. Тут либо делать словарь отдельно от метода ввода, либо по-другому запускать метод ввода. Но спасибо за помощь.